# Cannot see USB drive (even with sudo fdisk -l command)

Tags: partitioning, usb

Ubuntu newbie here.

I just bought a 3G USB key, and I need to install the software, which is found in the USB key itself. The problem is that Ubuntu cannot *"see"* it.

I found a couple of commands that I used such as `sudo fdisk -l` or `cat proc/partitions`  – but no success. I unplug the drive, use the command, plug it in, use the command, same result ...

Help! Also note: I'm using Ubuntu 12.whatever

Comment: If fdisk -l does not show the drive, then it's almost certainly a hardware problem, and there's little to nothing that you can do via software.

Comment: @ignsi: That highly depends. @ Zied: if still a problem, do not be afraid to update question with relevant information.

Answer (score 7):

USB keys should automagically be mounted and added to *"Places"*, `/media/` or `/media/username`  and the like.

A nice tool to use when handling USB devices is `lsusb`. It shows you all your hubs (USB ports) and connected devices. Use:

```
lsusb -v
```

for a very verbose output etc. As always `man <command>`, `<command> --help`.

---

In your case however, it seems like there are some trouble. Try:

```
tail -f /var/log/{kernel,dmesg,syslog}
```

*(<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> when done)*

Then unplug and insert the USB device. You should see some messages, and as it is not mounted, probably some notes about why. Update question with output if you are unsure.

---

To output it to file, so that you do not have to copy it from terminal, you could use `tee`:

```
tail -f /var/log/{kernel,dmesg,syslog} | tee some_file_to_print_to.txt
```

Then update question with output:

- Open file in e.g. gedit, gvim etc.
- Click [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/308533/edit) below your question.
- Paste in the contents of the file.
- Mark the text and press *"Code sample"* (`<$>`) from the menu line.

If it is very long paste it to [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and update question with the resulting URL (or URL's if you paste more then one).

---

Another nifty tool is:

```
udevadm monitor
```

Same procedure (if the output seems to be relevant).

---

If mounted you should also, beside `fdisk` and the less user-friendly `/proc/partitions` by:

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-id
```

`lsblk` is another way to list disks in a nice way.

Comment: Th output is too long..
I'm really confused

Comment: @Zied: What output?

Comment: Wait, by output, what do you mean?

Comment: @Zied: You said it: *"Th output is too long.. I'm really confused"*

Comment: Yeah I know. But I referred to what the console gave me (the result). I got confused and thought you were referring to something else.
Anyways Its impossible to copy it all here (restricted amount of characters)

Comment: @Zied: By *update question*, I did not mean you should add it as comment, but update your question. I have updated *"answer"* with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the device listed on `lsblk` but not in `sudo fdisk -l`

A restart of the OS fixed it for me though.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive works correctly, the drive should always automagically appear as a block device named `/dev/sdX` with usual setups. Lines similar to the following would also appear when you run `journalctl -k` or `sudo dmesg`, and you can see all sorts of useful information of it between `new USB device` and `Attached SCSI disk`:

```
[78614.567571] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[78614.588268] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=46f4, idProduct=0001,
bcdDevice= 0.00
[78614.588278] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[78614.588281] usb 2-1: Product: QEMU USB HARDDRIVE
[78614.588283] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: QEMU
[78614.588285] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1-0000:00:02.1:00.0-1
[78614.602766] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[78614.604700] scsi host7: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[78615.627980] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     QEMU     QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+
PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[78615.628783] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[78615.629306] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 41943040 512-byte logical blocks: =
(21.5 GB/20.0 GiB)
[78615.629539] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[78615.629543] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 63 00 00 08
[78615.629830] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled,
doesn't support DPO or FUA
[78615.631568]  sdb: sdb1
[78615.631731] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Immediately before `Attached SCSI disk` is a list of partitions, in the form of filenames as it appears in `/dev`. Other information here further identifies the USB drive.

Once the USB device's node name is determined, it can be manually mounted from the command line:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media
```