# Cannot see plugged-in USB disk drive in /dev

Tags: usb, hard-drive, usb-drive

I'm not able to see a plugged in USB drive in `/dev` in Ubuntu 22.04. Based on answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308533/cannot-see-usb-drive-even-with-sudo-fdisk-l-command), here is what I tried and the result:

- both `fdisk -l` and `lsblk` cannot see the USB drive,
- however, `lsusb` shows that the USB drive is connected to the USB bus and recognised:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
```

- I linked the full output of `lsusb -v -s 2:7` in the appendix.
- I tried to inspect the system logs with `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` while plugging in the USB drive and here is the output:

```
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.453128] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.477932] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.477945] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.477951] usb 2-1: Product: ASMT105x
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.477955] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: ASMT
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.477959] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 23456789017B
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.480419] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.480842] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu kernel: [ 1925.481006] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
Dec 14 10:45:41 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Dec 14 10:46:03 ubuntu kernel: [ 1947.215397] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
```

From the logs it looks like there is an issue when connecting the USB device (`bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device`). However, I'm not sure what does this mean. I'm considering trying the solution pointed out [here](https://superuser.com/a/1206665/909715).

## Question

My goal is only to clone this USB drive contents for data retrieval, not to mount it. For reference, its an old Mac disk drive formatted in HFS (GUID partition map) and it is not encrypted.

**Is there anything more I can do to inspect its data?**

---

#### Appendix

`lsusb -v -s 2:7` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x174c ASMedia Technology Inc.
  idProduct          0x55aa ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 ASMT
  iProduct                3 ASMT105x
  iSerial                 1 23456789017B
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002c
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
```